# Extracting word and/or string between two strings in R list

Tags: r, regex, substring

I'm parsing free text for a string such as: 
"ABC1: staining present in tissue" in order to identify present/absent, regardless of differences in white space in the strings.

Current approach is keeping the leading/lagging strings despite trying many approaches.

```r
test<-c("ABC1: staining present in tissue", "ABC1:  staining absent 
   in tissue", "ABC1:staining present  in tissue")

   unlist(regmatches(test, gregexpr("ABC1:\\s*staining\\s* (.*) \\s*in 
   tissue.*", test, perl=TRUE)))
```

Goal output for this could would be: present absent present

Answer (score 2):

You may use a solution based on lookarounds and `\K` since you are using a PCRE regex:

```
test<-c("ABC1: staining present in tissue", "ABC1:  staining absent 
   in tissue", "ABC1:staining present  in tissue")

unlist(regmatches(test, gregexpr("ABC1:\\s*staining\\s*\\K.*?(?=\\s*in\\s+tissue)", test, perl=TRUE)))
## => [1] "present" "absent"  "present"
```

Or a similar `stringr` approach:

```
library(stringr)
str_match(test, "ABC1:\\s*staining\\s*(.*?)\\s*in\\s+tissue")[,2]
[1] "present" "absent"  "present"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/2YnSHm).

**Details**

- `ABC1:\\s*staining\\s*` - matches `ABC1: staining` with any 0+ whitespaces at the end and after `:`
- `\\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the mempry buffer
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible (use `.*` to match as many as possible)
- `(?=\\s*in\\s+tissue)` - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ whitespaces, `in`, 1+ whitespaces, `tissue` immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach:use `str_extract_all`

```
> library(stringr)
> unlist(str_extract_all(test, "present|absent"))
[1] "present" "absent"  "present"
```